# jQuery UI remove element when dropped into a div using .droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm trying to figure out the logic of how to do this.

I have many images with only a CSS class name, they are created dynamically.

These images are draggable using jQuery UI's `.draggable.`

I need to have a "trash can" that when an element is dragged into , it is removed.

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/KWdcU/3/ (This is set to remove all elements and not the one dragged into it)

**Code**:

```
<div class ="box">
<div class="stack">one</div>
<div class="stack">two</div>
</div>
<div id="trash">trash</div>​



$(function() {
        $( ".stack" ).draggable();
});

$('#trash').droppable({
            over: function() {
             //alert('working!');
            $('.box').remove();
          }
    });
```

​

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find the item being dragged by using `.draggable` property of the `ui` element being passed to the callback function of `over`, as specied in the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-over). Like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".stack").draggable();

    $('#trash').droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

[Here's an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWdcU/495/).

---

From a usability standpoint, I'd recommend using the `drop` event rather than the `over` event, as it would be annoying to delete an item by dragging it unintentionally over the trashcan.

Comment: Thanks, that was a reading comprehension fail on my part, good idea for the 'drop'.

Comment: `ui.draggable.remove()` is also ok (without `$(...)`)

Comment: i fatch this error : i try to  your answer 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'remove' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 10):

Better to use drop in stead of over

```
$(function() {
    $(".stack").draggable();

    $('#trash').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Agreed, drop is a lot more user friendly and natural than over

Answer (score 0):

Delete the elements in droppable area by implementing the following JS Code :-

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-draggable', function(){
  if(confirm('Do you want to delete ?')){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

See the result :
[image: Result]