# Draggable: Drop to delete (remove) element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Ali Farhadi's HTML5 sortable jQuery plugin to make `<li>` elements draggable (and sortable) within an `<ul>`

http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/

I want to extend the functionality to also be able to *remove* elements from the list, and I thought an elegant UI for this would be to either drag the element into some "trash" `<div>` somewhere on the page, or maybe just drag it outside of the `<ul>` bounds (where the cursor turns into a "stop" icon).

However, I'm quite new to jQuery (although somewhat semi-proficient in JavaScript), so maybe someone can help me add this functionality to the js?

Comment: There's post about it

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796934/jquery-ui-remove-element-when-dropped-into-a-div-using-droppable][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796934/jquery-ui-remove-element-when-dropped-into-a-div-using-droppable

Good Luck

Comment: @Luan you realize that this is another plugin?

Comment: There's post about it

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796934/jquery-ui-remove-element-when-dropped-into-a-div-using-droppable][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796934/jquery-ui-remove-element-when-dropped-into-a-div-using-droppable

Good Luck

Comment: Use the `complete` callback to remove the dragged item like `$(this).remove()`

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, but I'm still at a loss. jQuery is new to me, so I really don't know more than the very basics. I can see where, in the code of `jquery.sortable.js`, the *drop* "event" happens, but I don't know how to check if it occurs within the `<div id="trash">`.
I've made a Fiddle, which also hints at another problem I'm trying to solve; how to add an "Add item"-button, which adds a new `<li>` which also becomes draggable (and deletable). Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/jokke/uxp12bjv/

Comment: I was able to "restart" the draggable plugin after adding a new `<li>`, by doing `$('.sortable').sortable('destroy');  $('.sortable').sortable();` Then, the new items become draggable, too. However, I still can't handle the *drop* or *over* callback at all (if that's what it's called).

Comment: Could there be some conflict between the html5sortable plugin, and the  javascript for the trash div?